# Will powder coating be durable enough for a closet pole?

Tags: finish

I'm making a steel pipe closet rod and was wondering if a powder coat finish would stand up to sliding metal hangers? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The best coating you could use is chrome plating. This is an industrial process you have done at a plating shop, but that would be silly for a bit of pipe since you can by chrome plated pipe off the shelf.

Powdercoating is not nearly as strong.

The problem with powdercoating is it's very hard to do yourself with a piece that large.  You need an extraordinarily large oven.  Sourcing small quantities of powdercoat is also a problem, this typically boils down to buying the dreck at Harbor Freight, which, I am glad they are making the tech available, but not gonna give you the durability you want.  *So if you're farming out the powdercoat job anyway*... Talk to the plater.

Answer (score 0):

A common demonstration by powdercoaters to show the durability of the surface is to beat on a powdercoated plate with a hammer. The underlying metal will sometimes dimple, but the coating will remain intact.

Your question bears more on friction and wear and such a demonstration is irrelevant.

Of all the possible coatings, it's likely that a powdercoated finish will give the best wear. You can request of the vendor to apply multiple coats to provide longer wear, but it will eventually show wear from metal hangers. It is common to have a clear coat applied over the primary color to provide even greater wear protection.

To mitigate this wear, consider to mount the rod in such a manner as to allow free rotation. You may have to perform manual rotation of the rod periodically, in order to present a new surface on which the hangers will wear, but it will increase the lifespan of the coating.

There are also plastic cylinders for such applications, known as [closet rod covers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0036Z3F5I), which are also advertised as being quieter for the hanger movement. No metal-on-metal screeching, but that's secondary to your question.

Comment: I have used powdercoating for years it is not very expensive and will hold up for years. I use a local company and they charge by the surface area and how much prep is required clean steel only requires a light sand blast then they electrostaticly coat the parts and bake. On my small job parts if I really don't care the color /shade they will work it in with another job and I usually get white, black or cream at a reduced price, if I want a specific color for a small job it cost more.

Answer (score 0):

Both of those processes, although they may be effective, are fairly expensive to have done on a one-off basis.  I would do a quick search on-line for closet rods.  A multitude of vendors will supply you with rods with any number of finishes for a fraction of the cost. I also believe a chrome finish would be the most durable.